# Can't connect to vpn over openVPN

Tags: networking, 16.04, openvpn

I constantly use vpngate.net service and it's been working fine on both 14.04 and 16.04 , but suddenly it stopped working.
I used to use the command

```
sudo openvpn --config file.ovpn
```

but now it gives me the same trace i used to ending with

```
Initialization Sequence Completed
```

but i keep getting the error

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG
```

`route -n` output while connected to vpn

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.211.1.90     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.211.1.90     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
126.219.236.196 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp2s0
128.0.0.0       10.211.1.90     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
```

without vpn:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around and found that I need to add two lines to the bottom of the conf file so that every time I use openVPN it modifies the  DNS configuration in the  `/etc/resolv.conf` file because it gets overwritten every time

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

then invoke the command

```
sudo openvpn --script-security 2 --config your-openvpn-config.ovpn
```

Found the answer [in this article on running OpenVPN with Ubuntu 14.04](https://prana.la/2015/04/28/vpngate-openvpn-with-ubuntu-14-04/)